# alphanumeric validation javascript without regex

Tags: javascript, html, validation, arraylist, alphanumeric

if i run, validation just can be work only on symbol "/", if I input the other symbol except / didnt working. I'm not use regex

```
if(nama!==""){
var i;
    var list = new Array ("/","!", "@", "#","$","%","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","+","=","-","`","~",";","<",">",".","?","[","]","{","}",",");

    var llength = list.length;
    for(i=0; i<llength; i++)
    {
        if(nama.match(list[i]))
        {
            alert("Full Name must not contain any number and symbol");
            return false;

        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: `I'm not use regex` That's what you think.  `.match()` uses regex, which is exactly your problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
    if(nama.indexOf(list[i])!=-1)
    {
        alert("Full Name must not contain any number and symbol");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Use `.indexOf`

Comment: didn't work. still can input another symbol except /